# Has anyone successfully built a PyObjC app in Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, pyobjc, py2app

If you did, would you mind sharing how you did the pyobjc install? I was trying to do it by installing PythonMac 2.5 (for the standalone bundle thru py2app), and doing `easy_install` of PyObjC. I always get those `deprecated` errors, primarily those declared in `dyld.h`, and inside `objc_inject.m`.

I tried compiling from source but still no luck.

Also, when I run my Leopard-compiled PyObjC app under Snow Leopard, it has errors concerning PyObjC, first time was it can't see `Foundation` or `AppKit`, second was `typestr` is unknown.

Thanks and appreciate your answers.

Comment: I thought PyObjC was built-in starting with Leopard? I did some very basic stuff with it a couple of years ago and didn’t have to install anything.

Comment: It is, but I'm trying to make a standalone app that works on both Leopard and Snow Leopard... with py2app, I only get semi-standalone apps using the System Python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found a way... though I dunno if this is official or what...

I downloaded 2.5 version of PythonMac, installed it, and then added a symlink inside the installation directory, e.g.:

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/site-python
```

This part made it seem as if the bundled PyObjC binaries are part of the PythonMac installation, and when I do `easy_install`, the system site-packages won't get affected. Also, worth noting is that you shouldn't conflict the system-bundled py2app by `easy_install`-ing py2app or else you'll encounter a typestr error.

I wanna know if there's anything wrong with this for me to be able to make a standalone PyObjC application under Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 4):

If you install the XCode Developer tools (optional Snow Leopard install), there's no need to manually install PyObjC at all. Here's how you can test it:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jul  7 2009, 23:51:51) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Foundation
>>> Foundation.NSString.stringWithString_(u'hello PyObjC')
u'hello PyObjC'
>>>
```

If the Foundation, AppKit, ScriptingBridge, modules can be imported, then everything is alright.

Comment: I would suggest using this method, it will make developing and testing much easier since you are using a standard system and standard python from Apple.